# Compute Intersection from multiple LineStrings using JTS

Tags: java, jts

I have 3 Lines defined as line A, line B and line C and will like to compute the intersection points between lines B and C with A. From JTS there's a function [LineIntersector](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/algorithm/LineIntersector.html#LineIntersector()) that should help accomplish this. I need help applying this function to the lines in order to find the intersection points, ie. Something like computeIntersection(line A, line B). Thanks!

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.*;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.algorithm.*;

public class PointTest {

public static void main(String[] args){

// We have to have an even number of arguments - to have coordinate pairs for points.

if (args.length % 2 == 1) {
  System.out.println("Wrong input. You did not enter a list of coordinage pairs. Try again.");
}


else {

  int i=0;
  String[] coordA = {"12", "2", "12", "13", "12", "19"};
  String[] coordB = {"2", "10", "10", "10", "21", "11"};
  String[] coordC = {"1","1", "9","9", "20", "20"};





  // Create a new empty array of coordinates.

  //Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[args.length/2];     

  Coordinate[] coordinatesA = new Coordinate[coordA.length/2];
  Coordinate[] coordinatesB = new Coordinate[coordB.length/2];
  Coordinate[] coordinatesC = new Coordinate[coordC.length/2];
  // Go through the args and add each point as a Coordinate object to the coordinates array.

  //Geometry g1 = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(coordinatesA);

  //System.out.println(g1);

      while (i < coordA.length) {
    // transform string arguments into double values
    double x = Double.parseDouble(coordA[i]);
    double y = Double.parseDouble(coordA[i+1]);
    double xx = Double.parseDouble(coordB[i]);
    double yy = Double.parseDouble(coordB[i+1]);
    double xxx = Double.parseDouble(coordC[i]);
    double yyy = Double.parseDouble(coordC[i+1]);
    // create a new Coordinate object and add it to the coordinates array
    Coordinate newCoord = new Coordinate(x,y);
    coordinatesA[i/2] = newCoord;
    Coordinate newCoordB = new Coordinate(xx,yy);
    coordinatesB[i/2] = newCoordB;
    Coordinate newCoordC = new Coordinate(xxx,yyy);
    coordinatesC[i/2] = newCoordC;
    //System.out.println(newCoordB.toString());    
    i=i+2;
  } // while

  // Create a new Geometry from the array of coordinates.
  LineString lineA = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(coordinatesA);
  LineString lineB = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(coordinatesB);
  LineString lineC = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(coordinatesC);
  System.out.println("Line A is "+ lineA);
  System.out.println("Line B is "+ lineB);
  System.out.println("Line C is "+ lineC);

  // Read the start and end point of the line and write them on the screen.
  Point startPointA = lineA.getStartPoint();
  Point endPointA = lineA.getEndPoint();
  //System.out.println("The start point of the line is: " + startPointA.toString());    
  //System.out.println("The end point of the line is: " + endPointA.toString());


} // else

 } //main   

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm maybe a notch above novice in using this API, but your problem is close to a problem that I've been working on and I can share what I've found so far. My problem is given two `LineString`s, find the point at which they intersect.  I have used the `LineIntersector` to solve my problem -- and it can solve your problem too -- but it's good to understand the more general problem that `LineIntersector` helps solve.

The first distinction that you want to make is whether the two `LineString`s *cross* or *intersect*.  When crossing, there are no `Coordinate`s that are shared, but the lines connecting at least two pairs of `Coordinate`s straddle each other. If the two `LineString`s intersect, there will be a point on one of the `LineString`s that falls within a "tolerance".  I use the `buffer()` method to specify the tolerance for matching:

```
if (lineStringA.buffer(0.0001).intersects(lineStringB)) { ... }
```

Similarly for testing (the less restrictive) crossing:

```
if (lineStringA.buffer(0.0001).crosses(lineStringB)) { ... }
```

If the two `LineString`s intersect, I found that it was straight forward to walk through each of the coordinates until I found the first one that lies on the second's `LineString`.  That common point would be the intersection.

If the two `LineString`s cross but do not intersect, I would get out the `LineIntersector.computeIntersection()` method to help out, but the interface for this method requires some preparation of the `LineString` to find the appropriate `Coordinate`s to use.

Here's the method I would use to walk the first `LineString` to find the two points which cross the second `LineString`:

```
private LineString findCrossingPair(LineString workingLineString,
        LineString fixedLineString) {
    // Pick up our factory instance
    GeometryFactory factory = fixedLineString.getFactory();

    Coordinate[] coordinates = workingLineString.getCoordinates();
    int length = coordinates.length;
    int indexOfCrossing = 0;

    // Walk the workingLineString for as long as it crosses the fixedLineString
    for (int i = 1; workingLineString.crosses(fixedLineString)
            && i < (length - 1); i++) {
        workingLineString = factory.createLineString(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(coordinates, i, length));
        indexOfCrossing = i;
    }

    Coordinate[] crossingPair = Arrays.copyOfRange(coordinates,
            indexOfCrossing - 1, indexOfCrossing + 1);
    LineString crossingPiece = factory.createLineString(crossingPair);

    return crossingPiece;
}
```

I call it once to find the first pair of `Coordinates` (returned as a `LineString`), and then turn it around to run it against the second `LineString`. Here's an example of calling the `findCrossingPair()` method twice to get the two pairs of Coordinates:

```
    LineString firstPiece = findCrossingPair(LineStringA,
            LineStringB);
    LineString secondPiece = findCrossingPair(LineStringB,
            firstPiece);

    // Now we have two 2-point LineStrings which we can pass to the
    // LineIntersector

    LineIntersector lineIntersector = new RobustLineIntersector();
    lineIntersector.computeIntersection(
            firstPiece.getStartPoint().getCoordinate(),
            firstPiece.getEndPoint().getCoordinate(),
            secondPiece.getStartPoint().getCoordinate(),
            secondPiece.getEndPoint().getCoordinate()
            );
    Coordinate intersect = lineIntersector.getIntersection(0);
    System.out.println("Intersection at " + intersect);
```

Note that in the general case, the `LineIntersector` can find 0, 1 or 2 intersecting points.  This is why the `LineIntersector` interface has an index which is passed to the `getIntersection()` method.  The test for crossing versus intersect limits the number of intersections that this procedure can find.

Comment: That seems super complicated, why not simply use Geometry#intersection() and test what comes out of it? Do you must use the specified coordinates of the line instead of allowing the "interiors" of the lines to intersect?

Comment: Agreed that this solution seems more complicated than it should be.

I may need to review the scenarios that gave me problems, but when I attempted using just the `intersection()`, it was missing the LineString pairs which *crossed*.  The interiors were not intersecting, but they did cross.

Comment: Huh! You mean the endpoint of a line laying on the interior of another line (afaik that would be `Geometry#touches()`)? `Geometry#intersection()` should result in a Point then. Floating point precision issue maybe?

Comment: @bugmenot123, I'm finding that the `Geometry#intersection()` is indeed doing what we want.  I'll need to amend this answer once I sort out why the `intersects()` is returning false when `crosses()` returns true, but certainly for the cases described in this question, I find your approach works fine.

Answer (score 3):

After reviewing @bugmenot123's answer, I've learned I've got more to learn, but I was able to put this together which answers the question using bugmenot123's approach.

It isn't yet clear to me under what circumstances I needed the long, complicated solution, but here's a solution to the posted question that appears to be working fine:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;

public class LineStringIntersect {

    static Coordinate[] coordinateArrayA = {
            new Coordinate(12.0, 2.0),
            new Coordinate(12.0, 13.0),
            new Coordinate(12.0, 19.0)
    };

    static Coordinate[] coordinateArrayB = {
            new Coordinate(2.0, 10.0),
            new Coordinate(10.0, 10.0),
            new Coordinate(21.0, 11.0)
    };

    static Coordinate[] coordinateArrayC = {
            new Coordinate(1.0, 1.0),
            new Coordinate(9.0, 9.0),
            new Coordinate(20.0, 20.0)
    };

    static GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

    static LineString lineStringA = geometryFactory
            .createLineString(coordinateArrayA);
    static LineString lineStringB = geometryFactory
            .createLineString(coordinateArrayB);
    static LineString lineStringC = geometryFactory
            .createLineString(coordinateArrayC);

    static Geometry geometryAB = lineStringA.intersection(lineStringB);
    static Geometry geometryAC = lineStringA.intersection(lineStringC);
    static Geometry geometryBC = lineStringB.intersection(lineStringC);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("AB: " + geometryAB);
        System.out.println("AC: " + geometryAC);
        System.out.println("BC: " + geometryBC);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any Geometry object has the geometric functions available. You can simply use `geometryA.intersection(geometryB)`. For example:

```
Geometry ab = lineA.intersection(lineB);
Geometry ac = lineA.intersection(lineC);
```

If you want to combine the results into one object, you could either use an array with `GeometryFactory#createGeometryCollection` or test which kind of geometry types you got and combine them to eg MultiPoint accordingly.